# How to invoke Mongoid model inside Sidekiq worker?

Tags: ruby, mongoid, sidekiq

Is it possible to write MongoDB document via Mongoid from Sidekiq worker?

```
# lib/worker.rb
require 'sidekiq'
require 'model' # lib/model.rb
class AwesomeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform
    RandomNumberModel.create! { random_number: Random.new.rand(1..100) }
  end
end
```

When I run Sidekiq it returns `uninitialized constant AwesomeWorker::RandomNumberModel`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try ::RandomNumberModel.create! { random_number: Random.new.rand(1..100) }

if it fails, you did mistake in path to required file

Comment: Thank you. I already tried workaround with invoking model outside of worker, passing `object_id` to worker and `ObjectSpace._id2ref`. But it is kind of dirty hack. So actually `$:` caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Might it help of anyone :)***

You have to create your worker under `app > workers` folder. Then every model will be easily accessible there.

```
# app/workers
class AwesomeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform
    RandomNumberModel.create! { random_number: Random.new.rand(1..100) }
  end
end
```